# Waterfall view - Gap between assets requests

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, pagespeed

I'm trying to increase the page load speed of our mobile web version of the website. Yesterday I've concluded that the page speed is influenced by the amount of requests we do to get the assets and some images so I did a quick fix to lazy load half of them.

Although I see a slight improvement in performance, I assumed that if I lazy load some images the DOMContentLoaded will occur early in the waterfall and the graph will be more compacted.

Yesterday the waterfall looked like this:

[image]

Today all the `medium_*` images are after the Page Load (red bar):

[image]

What bugs me now is why there is such big gap between `arrow_right_white` and `google_analytics` script (somewhere between 0.5s and 1 s) ? Does something is happening in that time? I can't see anything extraordinary in the profile.

[image]

Example link: https://www.autouncle.de/de/gebrauchtwagen/67165104-renault-kangoo-z-e-2-sitzer-klima

Comment: The browser may be doing something in those gaps. To view the internal V8 activity enable `chrome://flags/#enable-devtools-experiments`, restart, go to devtools, `Experiments` panel, tap `Shift` key 6 times, enable two "Show all ..." checkboxes and repeat the measurements.

Comment: I marked `show all events on timeline` and `show all processes on timeline` and restarted the browser. I still have that gap (and others) without an explanation.